# How to use LINQ to return substring of FileInfo.Name

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to convert the below "foreach" statement to a LINQ query that returns a substring of the file name into a list:

```
IList<string> fileNameSubstringValues = new List<string>();

//Find all assemblies with mapping files.
ICollection<FileInfo> files = codeToGetFileListGoesHere;

//Parse the file name to get the assembly name.
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string fileName = file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - (file.Name.Length - file.Name.IndexOf(".config.xml")));
    fileNameSubstringValues.Add(fileName);
}
```

The end result would be something similar to the following:

```
IList<string> fileNameSubstringValues = files.LINQ-QUERY-HERE;
```

Comment: There's no query here, just a transformation from A[] to B[].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var fileList = files.Select(file =>
                            file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length -
                            (file.Name.Length - file.Name.IndexOf(".config.xml"))))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Voted up: I prefer the extension method syntax to the query syntax here, since there's really no query: your goal is to perform a transform on all the elements.  There's no 'where' or 'orderby' or a crossing 'select' even 'select new { x, y }.

Comment: @Jay, I also prefer the extension method syntax for simple projections, the query syntax I think I only use it when doing joins...

Comment: better because 1) fluent interface 2) no brackets around the query needed

Answer (score 2):

```
IList<string> fileNameSubstringValues =
  (
    from 
      file in codeToGetFileListGoesHere
    select 
      file.Name.
        Substring(0, file.Name.Length - 
          (file.Name.Length - file.Name.IndexOf(".config.xml"))).ToList();
```

Enjoy =)

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to know the type of the collection of `FileInfo`s, and it's a `List<FileInfo>`, I'd probably skip the Linq and write:

```
        files.ConvertAll(
            file => file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - (file.Name.Length - file.Name.IndexOf(".config.xml")))
            );
```

or if it's an array:

```
        Array.ConvertAll(
            files,
            file => file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - (file.Name.Length - file.Name.IndexOf(".config.xml")))
            );
```

Mainly because I like saying "Convert" instead of "Select" to express my intent to a programmer reading this code.

However, Linq is part of C# now, so I think it's perfectly reasonable to insist that a reading programmer understand what `Select` does.  And the Linq approach lets you easily migrate to PLinq in the future.

Answer (score 1):

FYI,

```
file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - (file.Name.Length - file.Name.IndexOf(".config.xml")))
```

is the same as

```
file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.IndexOf(".config.xml"));
```

Also, if that string ".config.xml" appears before the end of the file name, your code will probably return the wrong thing; You should probably change IndexOf to LastIndexOf and check that the index position returned + 11 (the size of the string) == length of the filename (assuming you're looking for files ending in .config.xml and not just files with .config.xml appearing somewhere in the name).