# Linq throws exception on .Substring()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, substring

I've got a situation where I need to have my LINQ to Entities query return a substring depending on the length of the string. 
Here's the Query:

```
var query = (
    from f in Context.Files
    orderby f.DateAdded descending
    select new
    {
        Concerns = f.Concerns.Name,
        Sender = f.Sender.Name,
        CategoryCount = f.Categories.Count(),
        DateAdded = f.DateAdded,
        Comment = (f.Comment == null || f.Comment.Length < 5) 
            ? f.Comment : f.Comment
    }).Take(10);
```

So what I'm doing is getting the last 10 added Entities of type Files and then select a set of properties from it to display inside a listview. Some are plain strings (Concerns, Sender). CategoryCount returns the number of categories which are associated with the File object.

However, I want the comment to be truncated if it is longer then a given length. In the above code, everything is working correctly. Now when I replace this line:

```
Comment = (f.Comment == null || f.Comment.Length < 5) 
    ? f.Comment : f.Comment
```

With this line:

```
Comment = (f.Comment == null || f.Comment.Length < 5) 
    ? f.Comment : f.Comment.SubString(0,5)
```

the application throws a XamlParseException (???)

> The invocation of the constructor on type 'DocumentManager.Views.ListEntriesView' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception

I really don't know why it would do that. Is the SubString method not supported in LINQ?

Hope someone can help me here. Until then, I'll just leave it the way it is.

EDIT 2 (Somehow, my first edit got lost. So I'm redoing it): 
Based on the comments I got I changed my code to this and it works now:

```
var query = App.Context.Files.OrderByDescending(File => File.DateAdded).Take(10).AsEnumerable()
            .Select(File => new
            {
                Concerns = File.Concerns.Name,
                Sender = File.Sender.Name,
                CategoryCount = File.Categories.Count(),
                DateAdded = File.DateAdded,
                Comment = (File.Comment == null || File.Comment.Length < 100) ? File.Comment : File.Comment.Substring(0, 100) + "..."
            });
```

I forgot to mention that I'm using SQLite. So maybe Substring is not implemented in the SQLite EF Provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I would suspect substring isn't supported by Linq-to-Entities.  I would move your Take(10) to before your select statement, then after Take(10) call AsEnumerable(), then have your select statement after that.  That will cause you to pull back a collection of Files from the database, then the projection will be done in-memory.

Comment: @Brian Ball: How could Linq not support `Substring`? A method call is a method call, it does not matter if it is inside a Linq expression...

Comment: It does. Read about expression trees.

Comment: @rsenna, you're right about LINQ in general, but this not LINQ in general. This is Linq-to-Entities, and the method would be converted to an expression which would then be converted to SQL. That conversion might not be supported, in this case.

Comment: @Brian, please update your answer to be specific about non-support. LINQ as a whole is not the issue.

Comment: I will, though based on the tags int he question and the code, I thought it was fairly obvious that this question is based on Linq-to-Entities.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think the **constructor** call in the `select` clause will be converted to SQL... This is just plain C# code folks - there is no expression being generated there!

Comment: @rsenna, rest assured, this entire query will be translated to SQL.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: 1) yes, I mean the default constructor. 2) Prove me wrong - the query will be translated to SQL, yes, but the `new {...}` part is app-server-side only AFAIK. Maybe you're right, but I will not just take your word for it.

Comment: I don't know about the details and how Linq-to-entities translates into SQL, but Brian's solution did the trick. I'll post the code in case someone wants to see it. Btw, I'm using SQLite. So maybe it is related to the SQLite EF Provider?

Comment: @Gilles - When using a Linq Provider, it's up to the writer of that provider to decide what is/isn't implemented, so if you were to change the database and start using SQL Server, then your queries may stop working or work in a different fashion.  Hopefully not, it is a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

It's not LINQ's fault actually. Your model is bind to IQueryable, i.e. the routines directly supported by your database (everything else throws Exceptions). You should use AsEnumerable method at some point to do everything else.

Read more as Bill Wagner explains difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ff963710

Comment: Interesting article. I'll check it out when I've got time. Thanks for the link anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Correct  - LINQ doesn't support substring, but it's not always very clear from the exception when you try things like that unfortunaltely.

Comment: Please be specific. You can use Substring in LINQ. But it might not supported for all providers, such as Linq-to-Entities.

Comment: Sorry, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418187/how-to-use-linq-to-return-substring-of-fileinfo-name and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402529/substring-with-linq are some examples that you are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the SQLite parser because

- Substring works correctly to query into a SQL Server database with LINQ to Entities
- If you look in the generated SQL log, it generates it as Substring SQL function
- In SQLite, the correct function is substr, not substring

Thus, there is a bug in the way it is generating the query.

Here's a way to fix this bug.

In your database model, add this code right before EntityContainer

```
<Function Name="substr" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" ReturnType="nvarchar">
  <Parameter Name="text" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="startPos" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

In your context class (create a partial class next to it), add this code

```
[DbFunction("MyModel.Store", "substr")]
public string SubStr(string text, int startPos) {
    return text.Substring(startPos);
}
```

In your code, call Substring in this way

```
context.SubStr(text, startpos)
```

It will now properly map to the SUBSTR function instead of SUBSTRING! It's like mapping a User Defined Function, except that we map to an existing standard function.

Hope this helps!