# entity framework: join on the rule "A = substring(B)"?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Could I ask somebody show me the way how to declare the association between two entities 'Record' and 'DictionaryItem' if corresponded tables on the DB level are joined  by such interesting rule:

```
FROM Records R LEFT OUTER JOIN DictionaryItems D 
  ON SUBSTRING(R.CompositeKey,3,8) = D.DictionaryItemId
```

P.S. I'm now working with POCO entities.

Answer (score 0):

Linq-to-entities [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439873/linq-throws-exception-on-substring) `Substring`. You must either execute SQL directly by calling `context.Database.SqlQuery<>` or you must use Entity SQL - that would probably require converting `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` via `IObjectContextAdapter`, creating `ObjectSet` and running ESQL query.