# How to find substring in list of strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i need to find out a string from collection of strings using its sub string. This sub string 
must be in starting.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402529/substring-with-linq and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418187/how-to-use-linq-to-return-substring-of-fileinfo-name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
collection.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith(whatever))
```

Comment: Or, if there could be more than one, use `collection.Where(s => s.StartsWith(whatever))`

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this,

```
List<string> collection = new List<string>();
        collection.Add("example sample");
        collection.Add("sample");
        collection.Add("example");

        var varSubstring = collection.Where(x => x.IndexOf("sample")==0).ToList();
        foreach (var vartemp in varSubstring)
        {
        }
```