# How to locate a substring in a List<String> where the search function only looks for specified/delimited parts of the element? (in C#)

Tags: c#, string, list, search, delimiter

Similar questions:
[How to find substring in list of strings using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765231/how-to-find-substring-in-list-of-strings-using-linq)
[Find substring in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488587/find-substring-in-a-list-of-strings)

Question:
I'm wondering if there's a method provided in C# .NET 4.5 which takes in a string and a delimiter as arguments and returns the element or index of element in a given List where the string is found delimited by the delimiter. Something like what Foo(string searchStr, char delimiter) does below?

Code:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("XXX YYY ZZZ");
        list.Add("AAA BBB CCC");
        Console.WriteLine(list.Foo("XXX", ' '));    // should return 0 (index of element) or element of list
        Console.WriteLine(list.Foo("YYY", ' '));    // should return -1 or null
        Console.WriteLine(list.Foo("AAA", ' '));    // should return 1 (index of element) or element of list
        Console.WriteLine(list.Foo("DDD", ' '));    // should return -1 or null
```

Comment: IndexOf() should work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It doesn't work as IndexOf matches the case and doesn't work for finding substrings in a given string. Also, I would have to specify that I want to delimit by a blank space ' ', no overloaded IndexOf method does that.

Comment: Then you need to address your requirements more specifically in your question.  The obvious answer is "write a function that does what you want."

Comment: My question is sufficiently specified (if you read the comments of the code where I have explained the desired output of the method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("XXX "));
```

This will return the element. If there is no element starting with "XXX ", it will return `null`, because that's the default for strings.